# Why is shift faster than index access in this JavaScript example?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox, v8, shift

```js
// Shifting the array and accessing 0
let sum = 0;
while(matrix.length > 0) {
  sum += matrix[0][0];
  matrix.shift();
}
```

```js
// direct access
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  sum += matrix[i][0];
}
```

https://jsperf.com/shift-vs-index-access

Shifting the array and accessing 0 is faster than 
direct access in the given examples in the above jsPerf link.

Isn't `shift()` an `O(n)` operation?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a guarantee that `.shift` will be `O(n)`. It would be in something like an array-backed list but it can easily be `O(1)` in a linked list.

Comment: Just for reference, [I added a couple of cases](https://jsperf.com/shift-vs-index-access/3) to try and control for `for` vs `while` loop. Just in case that made a difference but it still seems that `shift` is faster by the same margin even if it's executed in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not faster. It's just your benchmark being broken. The `shift()` operation empties the `matrix` array, and after the first iteration you are comparing your codes on an empty array.

When you are benchmarking code that mutates your data structure, you need to re-create the data structure on every test run. [I've fixed your jsperf.com case](https://jsperf.com/shift-vs-index-access/6) and as expected `shift` is slower (notice that probably a large part of the execution time is spent on `createMatrix`, so in fact it's a *lot* slower).

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. My mistake. I was trying to illustrate a real issue I've seen.
I've updated your case with array of 1000 x 1000. Shift is still faster than index. https://jsperf.com/shift-vs-index-access/8

Comment: @ran That's weird, I cannot explain that. However, when you optimise `createMatrix` a bit then the `shift` run is (considerably) slower: https://jsperf.com/shift-vs-index-access/10